# Removing an item from a js prototype object with clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

In js I'd do:

```
delete myobj.prototype["mything"]
```

How is this accomplished with clojurescript?

Comment: See `js-delete`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36840548/500207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use built-in google closure wrapper around delete:

```
(goog.object.remove (.-prototype myobj) "mything")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never try it in production mode but this problem seems to be fixed according to this other os question [ClojureScript: How to add method via prototype to JS Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420003/clojurescript-how-to-add-method-via-prototype-to-js-object)

And this is my proposal to fix your problem:

Adding prototype property

```
(set! (.-foo (.-prototype js/String)) (fn [] "bar"))
(.-foo "test")
=>#<function (){return "bar";}>
```

Nulling this property

```
(set! (.-foo (.-prototype js/String)) nil)
(.-foo "test")
=> nil
(undefined? (.-foo "test"))
=> false
```

**And following the "undefined" mozilla description [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)  .**

```
undefined is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of undefined is the primitive value undefined.
```

Then I'll try with js/undefined

```
(set! (.-foo (.-prototype js/String)) js/undefined)
(.-foo "test")
=> nil
(undefined? (.-foo "test"))
=> true
```

good luck!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't delete the property from the prototype object, but just sets it to null.

Comment: @ngieschen You were right! I updated my response. Hoping now works for you!