# What is the ClojureScript analogue of delete from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I'm seeing lots of code using the pattern:

```
delete b[d];
```

Now I'm translating this to:

```
(aset b d nil)
```

Is that appropriate - or am I losing some crucial data?

My question is: **What is the ClojureScript analogue of `delete` from JavaScript? **

Comment: I think it's `dissoc` - deleting a property from an object in JavaScript removes that property completely; it doesn't just clear its value. The key is that `"d" in b` returns `false` afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://cljs.info/cheatsheet/ it's `js-delete`

```
(js-delete b d)
```